# Como borrar el Buffer de un Thread, por que se repiten los hilos(Threads)

Tags: c#, bucle-for, hilos

Tengo este codigo:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string f = "0.0.0";
        Program c = new Program();
        for(int i = 1; i < 255; i++)
        {
            Thread x = new Thread(() => c._scan(f, i.ToString()));
            x.Start();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Realizado con exito!");

        Console.WriteLine("Escaneo realizado!\nEncontrados " + x + " hosts.");

    }
```

Que ejecuta este metodo:

```
public void _scan(string subred, string num)
    {
        Ping _ping;
        PingReply _respuesta;
        IPAddress _ip;
        IPHostEntry _host;
        
            string _subred = "." + num;
            _ping = new Ping();
            _respuesta = _ping.Send(subred + _subred, 900);

            if (_respuesta.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                try
                {
                    _ip = IPAddress.Parse(subred + _subred);
                    _host = Dns.GetHostEntry(_ip);
                    x++;
                    Console.WriteLine( "Hostname: " + _host.HostName + " | " + "IP: " + _ip.ToString() + " | MAC: " + GetMacAddress(_ip.ToString()));
                }
                catch {   Console.WriteLine("IP:" + subred + _subred + " | MAC: "+ GetMacAddress(subred + _subred) + " Se desconoce");  }
            }
    }
```

Cuando ejecuto el con el hilo este me ejecuta la misma variable "i" mas de una vez, pero no siempre lo hace uno de tras del otro, miren lo que me lanza:

- Hostname: ---- | IP: 0.0.0.35 | MAC: -----
- Hostname: -- | IP: 0.0.0.56 | MAC: ----
- Hostname: --- | IP: 0.0.0.50 | MAC: ----
- Hostname: --- | IP: 0.0.0.56 | MAC: ----
- Hostname: --- | IP: 0.0.0.73 | MAC: ---
- Hostname: ---- | IP: 0.0.0.80 | MAC: --

Ahi solo les mostre las primeras 7 lineas, pero las repeticiones son muchas mas.

NOTA: CUANDO LO HAGO SIN EL HILO FUNCIONA CORRECTAMENTE, PERO NO DEBO EJECUTAR EL PROGRAMA SIN UN HILO POR QUE PUEDE TARDAR 9 SEGUNDOS POR CADA ELEMENTO, IMAGINATE ESCANEAR 225 COSAS Y QUE TARDES 9 SEGUNDOS POR CADA UNO.

Comment: ¿Cómo sabes que `i` se ejecuta más de una vez? y desde mi punto de vista existe un mal uso de lanzar el `Thread`, porque básicamente estás creando 254 hilos y en cuanto a la administración de del procesamiento me parece mala práctica. Antes de hacer algún ajuste la pregunta sería,¿por qué lanzar la ejecución en hilos?

Comment: Lo hago para hacer mas rapido el escaner. Son 254 IPs que tiene que analizar y si de esas 254 por lo menos 100 no responden estara esperando a cada una de esas hasta que pasen los 9 segundos determinados y esos son 900 segundos. Una persona promedio no esperaria ese tiempo. Si tienes una sugerencia de como lo puedo hacer que funcione rapido, que funcione bien y que no tenga hilos estoy abierto a tus sugerencias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, descubri la respuesta en un foro sin querer. [FUENTE](https://csharp.dokry.com/10147/mostrar-la-pantalla-de-espera-en-wpf.html)

```
public static void ForceUIToUpdate() 
    { 
        DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame(); 
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate (object parameter) { frame.Continue = false; return null; }), null);
        Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
    }
```

Debes ejecutar esto antes del Thread, esto obliga al Thread a actualizarse y asi el Buffer queda limpio. El motivo de la duplicacion era eso, el buffer almacenaba todavia informacion y esta tenia que ser liberara, pero con este metodo ya no.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string f = "0.0.0";
    Program c = new Program();
    for(int i = 1; i < 255; i++)
    {
        ForceUIToUpdate();
        Thread x = new Thread(() => c._scan(f, i.ToString()));
        x.Start();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Realizado con exito!");

    Console.WriteLine("Escaneo realizado!\nEncontrados " + x + " hosts.");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Las repeticiones son las lineas que quedaron en el buffer, por eso las repite. Proba de flushear la consola despues de cada WriteLine, lo haces llamando a:

```
Console.Out.Flush();
```

Comment: Te refieres a hacer esto? `Console.WriteLine("IP:" + subred + _subred + " | MAC: "+ GetMacAddress(subred + _subred) + " Se desconoce");
                        Console.Out.Flush();` Si es asi no me funciona

Comment: Lo pusiste en los dos WriteLine?.

Comment: Si, los puse y sigue igual.